# Как запустить все числа arrayLista в статическую переменную int через знак "|" (или)?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, arraylist, android-room

У меня приложение русско-английский словарь, в котором слова поделены на 4 категории (под номерами 0, 1, 2 и 3).
В настройках user может отключать какие-то из них, и мне нужно чтобы в этом случае слова с отключенной категорией
в процессе обучения не появлялись из базы. То есть чтобы Метод, описнный ниже, вызывал только включенные категории.

In Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE category = :category ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4")
Single<List<Word>> get4words(int category);
```

Затем в Repository я обзначаю цифру для категории:

```
public static final int CATEGORY = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3;
```

И заношу ее в метод, который вызывает список слов из словаря:

```
m4words = mWordDao.get4words(CATEGORY);
```

... Как я понимаю, нужен наверно аррайЛист с цифрами (чтобы отключая категорию пользователь удалял соот. цифру из аррайЛиста), а потом все значения этого листа запускать в статическую переменную int CATEGORY через знак "|" (или). Но как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно вариантов можно придумать несколько. Я бы предложил поскольку у вас всего 4 категории то комбинаций всего 16 штук. Так что на любые ваши комбинации достаточно 4х бит. И не нужно в этом случае никакого массива лиш правильно разбить переменную в sql чтоб узнать включение той или иной категории.

0 - 0000 все выключены

1 - 0001 включена 1 я

2 - 0010 включена 2 я

3 - 0011 включена 1 и 2 я

....

15 - 1111 включены все 4

Comment: Спасибо. А с АррайЛистом-то возможно?

Comment: Зачем не пойму Arraylist когда нужно всего 4 булевых поля максимум. А при желании можно обойтись и одной

Comment: ну слушатель к каждому SwitchButton-y будет менять только одну цифру, а как это делать? я же если например включаю первую категорию то будет ХХХ1 - что писать на месте Х-ов в слушателе, неизвестно же какая будет ситуация с остальными в тот момент.
Там 4 Switch-кнопки.

Comment: Если так сложно то введите поле boolean categoryOne, categoryTwo ... и включайте и выключайте сколько душе угодно

Comment: А с АррайЛистом невозможно? проще было бы гораздно, если б знать только как прописать.

Comment: По поводу включения каждой и выключению есть битовые операции примените маску получите что нужно.

Comment: @AlexRodionow, конечно возможно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48406229

Comment: Вот это то что надо спасибо